# How to group columns header in Table Grid with SWT, in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have a Table widget in a view, and I'm adding columns.
But I need to group headers. I want to have one title, for several columns.

I search a solution on web, but uses method that SWT seems to not have.

```
TableColumnModel cm = table.getColumnModel();
```

This is my table declaration:

```
table = new Table(content, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FILL);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nebula's [`Grid`](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php) and [`NatTable`](http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/) support grouped headers. Pretty sure neither SWT, nor JFace support it by default.

Answer (score 0):

The method you're asking about is for Swing `JTable`, not SWT's `Table` or JFace's `TableViewer`. You might find an example for doing what you want in the [SWT Snippets page](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#table).